# wp database some aria type tables break import to new server

Tags: wordpress, mysql-error-1064

I have backed up my wordpress site and database as I want to move to a new server.

I have a specific problem where I cannot import all the tables to the new database.  See attached. The tables of type aria cannot be imported.
[image: mix of table types]

Comment: If it is only for moving to new server, try All-in-One Wordpress-Migration plugin, its really easy and fast. You don't have to take care of DB individually

Comment: Your old host seems to be MariaDB while the new one is MySQL. Can you change the Storage Engine for the tables in question to MyISAM on the old server before exporting?